# awk command to change date format

Tags: shell

I have a file that contains the below records:

```
**cat Date.txt**
SEPT,30-SEP-2017
MARCH,30-MAR-2018
JULY,30-JUL-2017
DECEM,30-DEC-2017
AUGS,30-AUG-2017
```

I want the output to be:

```
    SEPT,20170930
    MARCH,20180330
    JULY,20170730
    DECEM,20171230
    AUGS,20170830
```

I have done a script with a while loop, as given below.

```
    cat Date.txt > /tmp/exp.part
    while read line
    do
    Dat=$(echo $line | awk -F , '{print $1}')
    DatNew=$(date -d $Exp +%Y%m%d)
    echo $DatNew
    done < /tmp/exp.part
```

I want to know if I can do it from the awk command, instead of writing a while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using system command within awk:
Input file:

```
$ cat file
27-SEP-2017
28-MAR-2018
27-JUL-2017
27-DEC-2017
29-AUG-2017


$ awk '{system("date -d " $0 " +%Y%m%d")}' file
20170927
20180328
20170727
20171227
20170829
```

For the updated input file:

```
$ cat file
SEP,27-SEP-2017
MAR,28-MAR-2018
JUL,27-JUL-2017
DEC,27-DEC-2017
AUG,29-AUG-2017


$ awk -F, '{system("date -d " $2 " +%Y%m%d")}' file
20170927
20180328
20170727
20171227
20170829
```

For the updated requirement:

```
$ cat file
SEPT,30-SEP-2017
MARCH,30-MAR-2018
JULY,30-JUL-2017
DECEM,30-DEC-2017
AUGS,30-AUG-2017

$ awk -F, '{cmd="date -d "q $2 q" "s"+%Y%m%d"s; cmd|getline x;print $1,x}'  dq='"' sq="'"  OFS=, file
SEPT,20170930
MARCH,20180330
JULY,20170730
DECEM,20171230
AUGS,20170830
```

Comment: Can you print your exact input file contents?

Comment: $ cat file
SEP,27-SEP-2017
MAR,28-MAR-2018
JUL,27-JUL-2017
DEC,27-DEC-2017
AUG,29-AUG-2017




$ awk '{system("date -d " $0 " +%Y%m%d")}' file
date: invalid date `SEP,27-SEP-2017'
date: invalid date `MAR,28-MAR-2018'
date: invalid date `JUL,27-JUL-2017'
date: invalid date `DEC,27-DEC-2017'
date: invalid date `AUG,29-AUG-2017'

Comment: Can you format your content better? I am not able to make out whether the whole content is in the same line or different lines?

Comment: Updated the solution

Comment: Perfect, but I want the first column as well. Which will be like:

SEP,20170927

Comment: Look how different is what you have put and what you actually want. Please make sure to give the correct input file to get the better response. Else, it gets into an endless loop.

Comment: Yes understood.. Apologize for the same.. I need the output to be: SEP,20170927

Answer (score 0):

Following on Guru's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45324938/3016497), this also seemed to work:

```
$ awk -F, '{cmd="date -d "$2" +%Y%m%d"; cmd|getline x;print $1,x}' OFS=',' file
SEPT,20170930
MARCH,20180330
JULY,20170730
DECEM,20171230
AUGS,20170830
```

Note the `awk` version was actually `mawk`:

```
$ awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan
```